# How to produce 'RowSpan' using primeNg p-datatable

Tags: angular, primeng

I've a table that should look like this.

```
+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| Product | Color | Type    | Stats    | 2016   | 2017   | 2018   |                    
+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| Nike    | Blue  |Sneakers | Qty sold | 150    | 167    | 251    |
|         |       |         +----------+--------+--------+--------+
|         |       |         | Price    | $17.99 | $18.99 | $21.99 |
|         |       |         +----------+--------+--------+--------+  
|         |       |         | Profit   | $600   | $750   | $1230  |   
+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------+--------+--------+     
| Converse| White |Sneakers | Qty sold | 145    | 151    | 201    |
|         |       |         +----------+--------+--------+--------+
|         |       |         | Price    | $17.99 | $18.99 | $21.99 |
|         |       |         +----------+--------+--------+--------+  
|         |       |         | Profit   | $550   | $450   | $930  |   
+---------+-------+---------+----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I'm trying the examples [from this page](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-4.3.0/#/datatable/rowgroup) but with no luck.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Share your work on Stackblitz for a kickstart.

Comment: which version of Primeng you are using

Comment: @AshokanSivapragasam I'm not familiar with that tool. I'll do my best to put there.

Comment: @TheParam I'm using *version 4.3.0*

Comment: @Richard77 I wonder if you find the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This could be your starting point. I am publishing the example in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-tableconfig-demo-xnydov?file=app/star-wars-table.component.html). I am interpolating  to specify the rowspan using PrimeNg. I could apply the rowspan for html table now. Please edit it to improvise this example as per requirements.

For future questions, please visit Stackblitz to publish the working example.